# Segmentation Fault Using cURL

Tags: c, curl, segmentation-fault, libcurl

I'm trying to download a test file from my server using the cURL library with this code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB

#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    size_t written;

    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;

    char *url = "http://pixhost.tk/test.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/Users/Nathan/Desktop";
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And compiling it like this:

```
$ gcc main.c -lcurl -o curltest
```

But when I execute it I'm getting a Segmentation Fault error. What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with cURL, but two things that might help you, so forgive me if I speak nonsense:

1. `char *url = "http://pixhost.tk/test.txt";` is a read-only string, so change it to `const char *url = "http://pixhost.tk/test.txt";` this might reveal your problem during compilation.
2. You don't check for the result of `fopen`, maybe it failed, which explains the segfault, and it is seems likely to me since you try to open "/Users/Nathan/Desktop" which should be a directory AFAIK.

Comment: Me too, a3_nm. It looks like he is trying to open a directory for write.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with curl, and I'm not sure this would cause a segfault, I think you should be calling fwrite like this:

```
fwrite(ptr, 1, nmemb * size, stream);
```

Because fwrite returns the number of elements written, and `size` is not (*I don't think*) guaranteed to be one. And since you're returning what fwrite returns, I believe you're returning less bytes than you're actually writing, since the function is supposed to return how many bytes it wrote.